# error: option --add-exports not allowed with target 8

Tags: maven, java-8, java-17, java-security

We have a requirement where we need our code base to be compiled with Java 17 and when the maven plugin generates artifacts it should be in Java 8 compatibility.

We are using sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction for security.

Maven plugin configurations are as below.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>         
      <compilerArgs>
         <arg>--add-exports</arg>
         <arg>java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
         <arg>--add-exports</arg>
         <arg>java.base/sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction =ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
       </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

When I run the mvn clean install I get the below error

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project security: Fatal error compiling: error: option --add-exports not allowed with target 8 -> [Help 1]

When I remove the --add-exports option I get

[ERROR] package sun.security.action does not exist

[ERROR] /Users/security/ScriptPolicy.java:[182,41] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class GetPropertyAction

Could anyone help us with how I can generate a Java 8 compatible jar file when I am using Java 17 in my IntelliJ?

Comment: "We are using sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction for security." Which methods of this class are you using? It's a very simple class, so you might be able to just replace it with a custom implementation, and drop the use of this internal class.

Comment: Also, if you're not running your code with a SecurityManager, you could just use `System.getProperty` instead.

Comment: In fact, its entire functionality can be replaced by a small lambda expression, `(PrivilegedAction<String>)() -> System.getProperty(name)` or `(PrivilegedAction<String>)() -> System.getProperty(name, defaultValue)`. Or, as Jorn Vernee already said, call `System.getProperty` directly when no `SecurityManager` has been installed (and mind that the entire security manager concept has been marked, *deprecated, for removal*.